# How to Use Case statement in Left outer Join using Operator +?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, outer-join

**Query:**

```
select /*+ full(c)parallel(c,4) */ a.* 
    from   ioct_inv_item_all a, 
    (select udac_group_name, function_order , db_region, workflow_type, change_level
     from ioct_function_target 
     where udac_group_name = 'Banner' 
     and function_name = 'emptyParam' 
     and workflow_type = 'CHGFCLTR' 
     and ('emptyParam' = 'emptyParam' or ('CHGFCLTR' != 'NEWITM' AND change_level = 'emptyParam') or ('CHGFCLTR' = 'NEWITM' and change_level = 'Simple') )
     and sysdate between effective_from_date and effective_to_date ) b , item_ca c ,product_ca d,assignment_ca ac ,branches b
    where  a.udac_group_name = 'Banner'
    and a.workflow_type = 'CHGFCLTR' 
    and a.DB_REGION = b.db_region (+)
    and a.workflow_type = b.workflow_type (+)
    and a.udac_group_name = b.udac_group_name (+) 
    and a.change_level = b.change_level (+)
    and a.product_code = c.product_code(+)
    and a.product_issue_num = c.product_issue_num(+)
    and a.item_id = c.item_id(+)
    and a.customer_id = c.customer_id(+)
    and c.product_code = d.product_code(+)
    and c.product_issue_num = d.product_issue_num(+)
    and c.product_issue_year = d.product_issue_year(+)
    and c.customer_id = d.customer_id(+)
     and (case when c.contract_assignment_id IS NOT NULL
                            AND c.contract_assignment_id > 0
                        THEN c.contract_assignment_id
                        ELSE d.regular_assign_id
                            END) = ac.assignment_id(+)
    and    ('emptyParam' = 'emptyParam' OR ('CHGFCLTR' = 'NEWITM' AND a.eue_normal_ind = 'emptyParam') OR ('CHGFCLTR' != 'NEWITM' AND a.change_level = 'emptyParam') )
    and    (('emptyParam') IN ('emptyParam') OR a.region IN ('emptyParam')) 
    and ('emptyParam' = 'emptyParam' 
        OR (b.function_order is not null and a.assignee_group_seq = b.function_order) 
        OR (b.function_order is null and 'emptyParam' =  'emptyParam')
```

**Error:**

> error:
>
> ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table
>   01417. 00000 -  "a table may be outer joined to at most one other table"
>      *Cause:    `a.b (+) = b.b and a.c (+) = c.c` is not allowed
>      *Action:   Check that this is really what you want, then join b and c first
>                  in a view.
>       Error at Line: 28 Column: 20

Does any body suggest any alternative to do same thing without using keyword LEFT OUTER JOIN because i do not want to change the structure of sql query already Written?

Comment: Can you post the full SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you start with a driving table and then outer join it to other tables. If a is your driving table, then

```
select x
from   a,b,c
where  a.x = b.x(+)
  and  a.y = c.y(+)
```

is the sort of query oracle expects in the join.

If you really want outer join a table with multiple "driving" tables, you can to use a syntax like this, as pointed out in the error description

Assuming you want to outer join "a" to both "b" and "c"

```
select *
from   a,
       (select *
        from   a,c
        where  c.y = a.y(+)
       )
where  b.x = a.x(+)
;
```

Comment: and (case when c.contract_assignment_id IS NOT NULL
                        AND c.contract_assignment_id > 0
                    THEN c.contract_assignment_id
                    ELSE d.regular_assign_id
                        END) = ac.assignment_id(+) ...i think this is causing issue

Comment: when i remove ELSE d.regular_assign_id it works but i need this also